# group the string name in arraylist by the first letter android

Tags: android

I would like to group the data in arraylist by the first letter ..give some logic to implement this. I have tried below like. Im not able to get get exact output.

a-america,Africa,Alwarpet,Antartica.
   b-bombay,bulgaria

I need this kind of grouping in list

```
ArrayList  allSampleData = new ArrayList<String>();
        data.add("America");
        data.add("Africa");
        data.add("Alwarpet");
        data.add("Antartica");
        data.add("bombay");
        data.add("bulgaria");
        data.add("dutch");
        data.add("delhi");
        data.add("Robert");
        data.add("Robert11");
        data.add("Robert111");
        data.add("Robert112311");
        data.add("zohoooo");

   for (int i = 0; i <data.size(); i++) {


            if (i==0)
                prevString=data.get(i).charAt(0);
            else
                prevString=data.get(i-1).charAt(0);


            if(prevString.equals(data.get(i).charAt(0))) {

                singleItem.add(data.get(i));
            }
           else
              {

             }
```

Comment: try java.util.Collections.sort(allSampleData)

Comment: this is will the sort data in to ascending...i want to group data..

Comment: you cant group data in a single list...create a hash map with key of unique groups and child of same group inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to group letter by place and store it in a map:

```
        Map<Character,List<String>> letterByCountry = new HashMap<>();

        ArrayList<String> allSampleData = new ArrayList<>();

        for(String p : allSampleData){
            if(!letterByCountry.containsKey(p.charAt(0))){
                letterByCountry.put(p.charAt(0), new ArrayList<String>());
                letterByCountry.get(p.charAt(0)).add(p);
            } else {
                letterByCountry.get(p.charAt(0)).add(p);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use that [Collections.sort](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List%3CT%3E)) for that:

```
Collections.sort(allSampleData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
String temp=new String();
    ArrayList<String> data=new ArrayList<String>();
     for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
     {
         for(int j = i + 1; j < data.size(); j++)
         {
         if(data.get(i).compareTo(data.get(j)) > 0)
             {
                 temp = data.get(i);
              data.set(i, data.get(j)) ;
              data.set(j, temp);

             }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin, you could make use of `groupBy`

```
val groupedNames: Map<Char, List<String>> = 
       allSampleData.groupBy { it[0] }
```

The groupBy here takes the first character of every item in the list as the criteria for grouping. It returns a Map with the character as key and a list all names starting with that character as the value.

If you wish to ignore capitalisation,

```
val groupedNames: Map<Char, List<String>> = 
       allSampleData.groupBy { it[0].uppercaseChar() }
```